# Which function is more efficient with respect to memory consumption?

Tags: javascript

I am new to the world of JS and I want to know which of the 2 methods is more efficient and will consume less memory? Will variable `queryParams` and the returned value both consume memory in the first method?

What are some of the good tools/ways to check memory consumption in JS?

**Method 1**

```
getQueryParamsForPreviousUrl(): string {
    let queryParams: string = '';

    if (this._currentUrl) {
      const index = this._currentUrl.indexOf('?');

      if (index !== -1) {
        queryParams = this._currentUrl.slice(index);
      }
    }

    return queryParams;
  }
```

**Method 2**

```
getQueryParamsForPreviousUrl(): string {

    if (this._currentUrl) {
      const index = this._currentUrl.indexOf('?');

      if (index !== -1) {
        return= this._currentUrl.slice(index);
      }
    }

    return '';
  }
```

Comment: Is this `TypeScript`? doesn't look like vanilla `JavaScript`. Also you didn't say what platform you're on. Tools for checking memory consumption will differ if you're using node, browser, etc

Comment: you can run both through https://jsperf.com/

Comment: Any benefit is likely to be optimized away in both cases.

Comment: If you have a memory issue, it's not from this function. Do not bother trying to optimize a one shot function anyway. Welcome to js, let the engine do the low level work for you (at least until you work with MBs of data, inside 60fps graphic animations and need the GC to never fire).

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Will variable `queryParams` and the returned value both consume memory in the first method?

**A:** `queryParams` will definitely consume some memory. What will happen here is that while your code is running method `getQueryParamsForPreviousUrl(...)`, the variable will be declared and store within the process's `stack` memory.

Once your code exits, `queryParams` will be marked as been "eligible for garbage collection", then some point in the future the consumed memory will be freed by the garbage collector.